# save and load input value with javascript or json

Tags: javascript, json

hello please help me find a solution:
there are **3 inputs** and the user can write whatever answer he wants in them;
and there is a "**SAVE**" Button that takes the values in the inputs and makes the user download them into a file.txt;
and then when he presses the "**choose file**" button he can load the input values in the txt file in the same inputs like it's been written right away (meaning reload every answer in its input)

Nb: the saved file can be in any format not exactly ["111","222","333"]

```js
function save_func() {
  var quest1 = document.getElementById("Question1").value;
  var quest2 = document.getElementById("Question2").value;
  var quest3 = document.getElementById("Question3").value;
  var data = [];
  data.push(quest1);
  data.push(quest2);
  data.push(quest3);
  var data_string = JSON.stringify(data);
  var file = new Blob([data_string], {
    type: "text"
  });
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  anchor.download = "MyProject.txt";
  anchor.click();
}

function load_func() {
  var file = document.getElementById("load").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var load = JSON.parse(reader.result)[0];
    document.getElementById("inputs").value = load;
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

```html
<form id="inputs">
  <label for="Question1">Question 1</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="Question1" class="input-box" name="Question1name" /><br />
  <br />
  <label for="Question2">Question 2</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="Question2" class="input-box" name="Question2name" /><br />
  <br />
  <label for="Question3">Question 3</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="Question3" class="input-box" name="Question3name" /><br />
  <br />
  <button onclick="save_func()">Save</button> And To Load A Project <input id="load" type="file" value="load" onchange="load_func()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only issue with your code is that you are not actually loading the file back into any of the inputs on your page. Your `load_func` function is trying to set the value of an input with the id of "**inputs**" which is a form, not an input. So you just need to load your values back into "**Question1**", "**Question2**", and "**Question3**".

```js
function save_func() {
  var quest1 = document.getElementById("Question1").value;
  var quest2 = document.getElementById("Question2").value;
  var quest3 = document.getElementById("Question3").value;
  var data = [];
  data.push(quest1);
  data.push(quest2);
  data.push(quest3);
  var data_string = JSON.stringify(data);
  var file = new Blob([data_string], {
    type: "text"
  });
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  anchor.download = "MyProject.txt";
  anchor.click();
}

function load_func() {
  var file = document.getElementById("load").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var load = JSON.parse(reader.result);
    document.getElementById("Question1").value = load[0];
    document.getElementById("Question2").value = load[1];
    document.getElementById("Question3").value = load[2];
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

```html
<label for="Question1">Question 1</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="Question1" class="input-box" name="Question1name" /><br />
<br />
<label for="Question2">Question 2</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="Question2" class="input-box" name="Question2name" /><br />
<br />
<label for="Question3">Question 3</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="Question3" class="input-box" name="Question3name" /><br />
<br />
<button onclick="save_func()">Save</button> And To Load A Project <input id="load" type="file" value="load" onchange="load_func()">
```

**EDIT**

Below is a code snippet that is designed to work with any number of inputs/fields. Any input that has a class of `input-box` will be saved and consequently loaded. The code snippet above still works based on OP's example, but the code below would probably work better for most real-world applicaitons.

```js
const _Save = () => {
  let data = [];
  document.querySelectorAll(".input-box").forEach(el => {
    data = [...data, el.value];
  });

  let file = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
    type: "text"
  });

  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = "SavedData.txt";
  a.click();
}

document.querySelector("#load").addEventListener("change", e => {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    let data = JSON.parse(reader.result);
    document.querySelectorAll(".input-box").forEach((el, i) => {
      el.value = data[i];
    });
  };
  reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
});
```

```html
<label for="Question1">Question 1</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="Question1" class="input-box" name="Question1name" /><br />
<br />
<label for="Question2">Question 2</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="Question2" class="input-box" name="Question2name" /><br />
<br />
<label for="Question3">Question 3</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="Question3" class="input-box" name="Question3name" /><br />
<br />
<button onclick="_Save()">Save</button> And To Load A Project <input id="load" type="file" value="load">
```

Comment: thanks so much, it worked very well and if you can help me edit the save function so instead of getting txt file in a format of: ["answer1","answer2","answer3"]  I want it to be like that inside the file: answer1 back to line answer2 back to line answer3

Comment: @DevSamurai I'm not sure I understand the format you want the file in. Could you give me a specific example of what the contents of the file should look like, and wrap that inside of *``* characters so it shows up as a code block (`like this`)

Comment: really sorry to be late i hadn't get a notification for your comment please if you can help me: -i want the user to choose the name of the saved file. -and when the file is saved the format of data inside the file is like this ["input1 value","input2 value","input3 value"] and want it to be lie that : input1 value \n input2 value \n input3 value (\n mean back to new line)